# WebBrowser DocumentCompleted event fired more than once

Tags: c#, .net

I've been researching this stuff and everyone seems to agree that the solution is to check the `ReadyState` of the Web Browser until is set to Complete.

But actually the event is sometimes fired with the `ReadyState` set to Complete several times.

I don't think there is a solution with that crappy .NET WebBrowser, but there might be one if I use the underlying DOM component.

Only problem is, I have no idea how do access the DOM component behind the WebBrowser that fires the DocumentCompleted event.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

DocumentCompleted will fire for each frame in the web page.  The hard way is to count off the frames, shows you how to access the DOM:

```
private int mFrameCount;

private void startNavigate(string url) {
  mFrameCount = 0;
  webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
}

private void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
  mFrameCount += 1;
  bool done = true;
  if (webBrowser1.Document != null) {
    HtmlWindow win = webBrowser1.Document.Window;
    if (win.Frames.Count > mFrameCount && win.Frames.Count > 0) done = false;
  }
  if (done) {
    Console.WriteLine("Now it is really done");
  }
}
```

The easy way is to check the URL that completed loading:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.Equals(webBrowser1.Url)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Now it is really done");
    }
}
```

Comment: The easy way of this answer did it for me.  Even though I'm using axWebBrowser1 control.  I ended up using the following.  if (e.uRL.Equals(axWebBrowser1.LocationURL))

Comment: I use a static helper class :

`public static class WebBrowserHelper {
        public static bool DocumentIsReallyCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
            WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
            return e.Url.Equals(browser.Url);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This would probably happen if the page uses Javascript or `<meta refresh>` to redirect to another page.

If so, there's no good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything that will give 100% certainty.
Mentioned example (e.Url.Equals(webBrowser1.Url)) may work for a simple WebBrowser.Navigate(url), however, in my case I click nodes in code to open new frames in existing frames. Mostly the number of times "Navigating" and "DocumentCompleted" fire will be the same, but again NOT always. "isBusy = false" and "ReadyState = Complete" will always be the case when it's finished (at least so far) but it will also a few times have this state when it's still loading. Counting frames also seems useless for me, in one case DocumentCompleted  is fired 23 times, however, all frames and sub(-sub-sub and so on) frames are 14 in total.

The only thing that seems to work is wait a short period (1 or 2 seconds?) to see if anything happens (any events fired, any state changes).

Hmm, I found another solution for me. Often we're not interested in the whole page being loaded, often we want certain elements to exists. So after each DocumentCompleted and when "isBusy = false" and "ReadyState = Complete" we can search the DOM if this element exists.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's impossible to tell when a web page has finished loading until DocumentCompleted hasn't fired for a while. So I refresh a timer for around 1000ms every time the DocumentCompleted event triggers. Then when the timer times out I process the web page.