# WebBrowser URI in Listbox

Tags: c#, browser

How to get the URI from webbrowser in listbox?? 
this code add a 20 URI not 1:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 

WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    radListControl1.Items.Add(webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
}
```

or

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    radListControl1.Items.Add(webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (!radListControl1.Items.Contains(webBrowser1.Url.ToString()))
     radListControl1.Items.Add(webBrowser1.Url.ToString());
```

Because this event is fired multiple times in single page load...

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the URI provided by the event against the one in browser:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Url.Equals(webBrowser1.Url)) 
    // this is the real one
}
```

EDIT: actually, [it has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239204/webbrowser-documentcompleted-event-fired-more-than-once).