# I'm getting InvalidCastException while actually casting nothing

Tags: c#, casting, browser

```
AutoResetEvent receiver = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Thread t = null;
            t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {

                while (Browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) // error
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                receiver.Set();
                t.Abort();
            }));
            t.Start();

            // Timeout
            success = receiver.WaitOne(10000);
```

Browser is

```
public WebBrowser Browser { get; set; }
```

[image: Screenshot]

I don't really understand why I get such error. The Browser.ReadyState is a enum type `WebBrowserReadyState`

So what do you think?

EDIT:
**First:**
[image: SS1]
**Second:**
[image: SS2]

Comment: Whats the full name? (i.e System.Windows.forms.WebBrowserReadyState) I suspect these are different

Comment: I think you should get rid of `t.Abort();`. You don't need it.

Comment: Probably the exception is *inside* `Browser.ReadyState`, not in your method.

Comment: @Sayse check screenshots, CodeCaster I'm checking it right now

Comment: Definitely duplicate question then

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried invoking it but when I invoke webbrowser things get worse I'm getting really horrible errors like HRESULT returned E_FAIL or COM component errors etc. etc.

Comment: I think I should stick with invoking thread and try to handle other errors.

Comment: I'm curious why you are doing this in a thread.. given that the browser will navigate asynchronously anyway..

Comment: Actually I'm trying to catch when this browser FULLY completes loading I mean sometimes it raises the DocumentCompleted event multiple times and I found  after my researchs that the ReadyState set Completed after it FULLY loads.

Comment: Aaand my "possible duplicate"-comment was deleted again, even though I edited it. [FIX IT](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified).

Comment: The InvalidCastException is raised because the Document property cannot be accessed in a worker thread.  Used by the ReadState property getter.  The underlying call that fails is IUnknown::QueryInterface() for the IMarshal interface.  The real solution you are looking for [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3239313/17034)