# How to determine the source of DocumentCompleted in WebBrowser control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Microsoft in a [KnowledgeBase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180366/en-us) suggests that I should have the following code in place to properly detect `DocumentCompleted` (this is VB code that I guess is trying to talk to the COM object):

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
   If (pDisp Is WebBrowser1.Object) Then
      Debug.Print "Web document is finished downloading"
   End If
End Sub
```

`pDisp` points to the frame object (or the document object if there are no frames in the page) that raised `DocumentCompleted` event. Now my question is how can I do the same thing for a WinForms WebBrowser control? The DocumentCompleted here has an `object sender` parameter, but that always points to the WebBrowser control itself, not the child frames.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebBrowser DocumentCompleted event fired more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239204/webbrowser-documentcompleted-event-fired-more-than-once)

Comment: I handle this by observing `onload`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18370524/1768303