# How to use HtmlElement in if statement [webbrowser/winforms] in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, webbrowser-control

How can I change this foreach loop into an if statement. It shows message for every image [EVEN IF I click on only one]. I only want to show a message on click of picture...

[code]

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, CompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement ele in
                     webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img"))
            {
                ele.AttachEventHandler("onclick", Document_Click);
            }
        }

 private void Document_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("You clicked an image.");
        }
```

[what i've tried]

```
 if (webBrowser1.Document.GetType().GetElementType().Equals("img"))
 {
    // I tried this
 }

 HtmlElement elemz;
 if (elemz.GetAttribute("type").Equals("img"))   
 {
    // And this
 }

 HtmlElement elemz;
 if (elemz == webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img"))
 {
    // Also this
 }

 if (webBrowser1.Document.GetType("img") == true)
 {
    // Finally I tried this
 }

 HtmlElement elemz;
 if (elemz.GetAttribute("type") == webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img"))
 {
    // My last hope was this 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that the click event is showing for every image, it's because the DocumentCompleted event is firing multiple times. (see [WebBrowser DocumentCompleted event fired more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239204/webbrowser-documentcompleted-event-fired-more-than-once)). If you check e.Url to make sure you are only running your code for the actual page DocumentCompleted you'll see the event only fires once.

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Url.Equals(webBrowser1.Url)) {
            foreach (HtmlElement ele in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")) {

                ele.AttachEventHandler("onclick", Document_Click);
            }
        }
    }
```